# Distance between origin and orthocentre in 3d space

Tags: geometry, 3d

The plane x/1+ y/2+ z/3= 1 intersect x–axis, y–axis, z–axis at A, B, C respectively. Find the distance
between origin and orthocentre of triangle ABC.

My attempt: I found the triangle coordinates in 3D space but using direction cosine to find equation of line and then finding orthocentre seems pretty tough.  Is there any other way to do this?

The solution states only one line ---orthocentre is the foot of perpendicular from origin on the plane. This seems completely weird to me and possible maybe but i have no idea how.
Well I found this answer regarding a similar question but me being a high school student could anyone prove this without barycentric coordinates ?
The link is as follows.

[Coordinates of orthocentre,circumcentre and incentre of a triangle formed in 3d plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125459/coordinates-of-orthocentre-circumcentre-and-incentre-of-a-triangle-formed-in-3d)

Comment: The $x$- coordinate of orthocentre is $$\left(\frac{\sum_{cyc}x_1\tan\alpha}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta+\tan\gamma}\right).$$ Same for $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a consequence of the [Theorem of Three Perpendiculars](https://www.math-only-math.com/theorem-of-three-perpendiculars.html).

Let $O$ be the origin: $AO$ is perpendicular to plane $OBC$ and, as a consequence of the above theorem, the projection $D$ of $O$ on line $BC$ is also the foot of the altitude $AD$ in triangle $ABC$.

On the other hand, if $H$ is the projection of $O$ on plane $ABC$, then by the same theorem $HD$ is perpendicular to line $BC$. It follows that $H$ lies on altitude $AD$.

But the argument can be repeated for the other vertices of $ABC$, hence $H$ also lies on the other altitudes of the triangle, and is therefore the orthocentre of $ABC$.

Comment: Yes it seems a bit forced hypothesis like could you say why should the perpendiculars coincide?

Comment: @Alex Because the perpendicular from point $D$ to line $BC$ in plane $ABC$ is unique. If lines $HD$ and $AD$ are both perpendicular to $BC$, then those lines must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

To find the orthocentre you can do the following steps -

1. Find the projection of any of the 2 coordinate axes on the plane which is intersecting the coordinate axes to form the triangle.
2. Find the intersection point of these projected lines.

Result is same as taking the projection of Origin on the plane.